# Trying to print the factorial of natural numbers using generators .Getting the output as 1 1 1 1 1 instead of 1 1 2 6 24 120 ......?

Tags: python

```
def my_gen():
    number = 1
    fact = 1
    fact = fact * number //Trying to calculate factorial
    yield fact
    number  = number + 1

a = my_gen()
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
```

Trying to print the output for the first five natural numbers.
Expected output: 1 1 2 6 24
obtained output: 1 1 1 1 1
How can i do this??.Any help is appreciated

Comment: I only get the first number followed by a `StopIteration` error.

Comment: The same error .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write this as a generator, you might want to look up how that works. The generator somehow has to to repeatedly yield a value, your function just provides a single yield, i.e. there is no "next". A fix, working for arbitrarily sized factorials, could involve `itertools.count` like so:

```
from itertools import count
def factorial():
    res = 1
    for x in count(1):
        res = x*res
        yield res
```

This starts with the value 1, after each iteration multiplying with the next higher number, and yielding that result.
Should you want to get the first value, 1, twice, then insert another `yield res` before entering the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to solve your problem.

```
 def my_gen(num):
      if num < 0:
         return 0
      elif num == 0:
         return 1
      else:
         for i in range(1,num + 1):
             factorial = factorial*i
         return factorial

    a = 1
    print(my_gen(a))
    a = a+1
    print(my_gen(a))
    a = a+1
    print(my_gen(a))
    a = a+1
    print(my_gen(a))
    a = a+1
    print(my_gen(a))
```

Comment: OP is looking for generator, not the function (`yield` vs `return`)

Comment: exactly ...you can change your code according to that

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri he didn't mention to use yield. he wants to get respective natural number factorial.

Comment: @VarunKumarKaja he mentioned the use of generators. This implies `yield`.

Comment: Question says *"Trying to print the factorial of natural numbers **using generators** .Getting the output as 1 1 1 1 1 instead of 1 1 2 6 24 120 …?"*

Comment: hey sorry, I didn't look into it.

Comment: am looking for an answer which uses yield.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code

```
from itertools import count
def factorial():
    res = 1
    for x in count(1):
        yield res
        res = x*res

fs = factorial()
for item in range(10):
    print(next(fs))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(x):
    start = 0
    fact = 1
    while start <= x:
        yield fact
        start = start + 1
        fact = fact * start
fact = factorial(5)
print(next(fact))
print(next(fact))
print(next(fact))
print(next(fact))
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your answer rather than just posting the plain code.

Comment: The number starts with 0 and increase with while loop. On each iteration,it will multiply with start value. Output is 1 1 2 6.